# Apache beam and BigQuery

Tags: java, google-bigquery, apache-beam

I'm trying to execute apache beam sdk 2.4 and the libraries com.google.cloud.bigquery but thow exception

```
Exception in thread main java.lang.NoSuchMethodError com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClient$Builder.setBatchPath(LjavalangString;)LcomgoogleapiclientgoogleapisservicesAbstractGoogleClient$Builder;
at com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery$Builder.setBatchPath(Bigquery.java3519)

import com.google.cloud.bigquery.*;

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.dataflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all</artifactId>
    <version>[2.4.0, 2.99)</version>
</dependency>

<!-- slf4j API frontend binding with JUL backend -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <versi

on>1.7.14</version>
    </dependency>

   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-bigquery</artifactId>
        <version>1.35.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

> ```
> the code example apache beam 2.4 using
> ```

```
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableFieldSchema;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableSchema;
```

> If I use the the libraries om.google.api.services.bigquery. the code
> example run successfully .
>
> What library is it using internally?
>
> What library should I use? com.google.api.services.bigquery or com.google.cloud.bigquery?

Answer (score 3):

Beam 2.4 is using [com.google.api.services.bigquery](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/ae2e12ac3c7dcc3831b185407853331f5d383e0c/pom.xml#L1049) v2-rev374-1.22.0. This is also the library that you should use with Beam 2.4. The com.google.api.services.bigquery library is out of date and there is an [open issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-4248) to upgrade it. Unfortunately other components in Beam depend on libraries which are incompatible with com.google.cloud.bigquery, and those need to be upgraded before the new library can be used.

If you aren't already doing so, you should take a look at the [BigQuery IO](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.4.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.html), which provides a wrapper to common BigQuery operations for Beam.

Comment: I don't found how get tables from a dataset specified. I want use Dataflow for migrate tables since Dataset US to dataset location EU. I would like get all tables in paralel process of dataset US and write the tables in dataset EU. I don't found the method get scheme of the  exist table  in dataset EU. Could you help me please?

Comment: Please open a new question for the second issue that you want to discuss for the benefit of the community.