# Apache Beam Dataflow BigQuery

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

How can I get the list of tables from a Google BigQuery dataset using apache beam with DataflowRunner?

I can't find how to get tables from a specified dataset. I want to migrate tables from a dataset located in US to one in EU using Dataflow's parallel processing programming model.

Comment: please do tag if you are using java or python. Thanks!

Comment: using java, apache dataflow with python has some open issues...

Answer (score 0):

## Declare library

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
```

## Prepares a bigquery client

```
client = bigquery.Client(project='your_project_name')
```

## Prepares a reference to the new dataset

```
dataset_ref = client.dataset('your_data_set_name')
```

## Make API request

```
tables = list(client.list_tables(dataset_ref))
if tables:
    for table in tables:
        print('\t{}'.format(table.table_id))
```

Reference:
https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/usage.html#datasets

Comment: I need the code in java, also beam 2.4 is using com.google.api.services.bigquery v2-rev374-1.22.0. This is also the library that you should use with Beam 2.4.

Comment: code reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51101842/how-dataflow-works-with-bigquery-dataset?noredirect=1#comment89259803_5110184

Answer (score 0):

You can try using google-cloud-examples maven repo. There's a class by the name `BigQuerySnippets` that makes a API call to get the table meta and you can fetch the the schema. Please note that the limit API quota is 6 maximum concurrent requests per second.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of Dataflow is to create pipelines, so the ability to make some API requests is not included. You have to use the BigQuery Java Client Library to get the data and then provide it to your Apache Pipeline.

```
DatasetId datasetId = DatasetId.of(projectId, datasetName);
Page<Table> tables = bigquery.listTables(datasetId, TableListOption.pageSize(100));
for (Table table : tables.iterateAll()) {
  // do something
}
```